# Cannot save ggplot2 graph with ggsave on Mac

Tags: r, graphics, export, ggplot2, osx-mountain-lion

After successfully creating a graph with this code:

```
qplot(ethcat3, Percent, data=g_02_1b_pov, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

I would like to save the graph as a png, pdf, or jpeg file. I used the following code:

```
ggsave(ﬁle="test.png")
```

Instead of outputting the graph, I receive the following (error) message:

```
Saving 7.82 x 3.75 in image
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function
```

and no file is saved. (Instead of png, I also tried the extensions pdf, and jpeg).

I found in a forum that I should use the command: dev_mode() and has_devel()

the output of dev_mode is:

```
> dev_mode()
Dev mode: OFF
```

and

```
> has_devel()
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R --vanilla CMD SHLIB foo.c 

sh: make: command not found
Error: Command failed (1)
```

However, I don't know what to do with this feedback?

Can anyone help me with this problem? I think I used the same approach in the past on a PC and it worked without a problem. I'm wondering if it is connected to my installation on a mac?

Thanks a lot!

Addition: @DWin asked for the `sessionInfo()` output:

```
d> sessionInfo() 
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_0.8    reshape2_1.2.1  plyr_1.7.1      ggplot2_0.9.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-18        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 RCurl_1.95-3       colorspace_1.2-0  
 [5] dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       evaluate_0.4.2     grid_2.15.1       
 [9] gtable_0.1.1       httr_0.2           labeling_0.1       memoise_0.1       
[13] munsell_0.4        parallel_2.15.1    proto_0.3-9.2      scales_0.2.2      
[17] stringr_0.6.1      tools_2.15.1       whisker_0.1
```

Comment: what happens if you omit `device=png`?  It should be unnecessary anyway (`ggsave` looks at the file extension to guess by default)

Comment: I think you should use quotes around `png`, like this `..., device="png"`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with the example in the `ggsave` help page and addition of a `device=pdf` or `device=png`. I'm using R 2.15.2 and ggplotggplot2_0.9.2.1 and  lattice_0.20-6 also happens to be loaded (along with a fair number of attached namespaces which I think are mostly from ggplot2).

Comment: @Andrie: The idea of quoting the device-function occurred to me but causes an error using my setup: "could not find function "device""

Comment: do you happen to have defined variables called `png`, `pdf`, and `jpeg`, that `ggplot` could be finding by mistake ... ?  What happens if you run from a clean session with `--vanilla` ... ?

Comment: I think its time for the questioner to "come clean" with sessionInfo()

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! @BenBolker: the error message is the same with and without `device=png`. Also, I have no variables that are called `png, pdf` or `jpeg`. You last comment I don't understand: What does it mean to run a clean session with `--vanilla`? @DWin: I will add the sessionInfo() output to the question.

Comment: "a clean session ..." means invoking R with a command-line option to prevent existing `.RData` files from being read in.  This is stumping me: there's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing.  What are the results of `traceback()` (executed right after you get the error message) ?  I think the `dev_mode()` stuff is a red herring, by the way -- what you're doing should just work.

Comment: Now we know you have a reasonably up-to-date version of R (although not exactly the same as the current version.) We also know you have reasonably updated packages. My suggestion is to update to R 2.15.2 and if it still fails (as I expect it to since I am on R 2.15.1 on this machine as well)  to post that dataset using `dump()` or `dput()`.

Comment: I can report that using png format on a Mac (10.6.8, R 2.15.2, ggplot2_0.9.2.1)  fails to generate what is says it is generating (a 7 in x 7 in plot). You instead get a tiny square with no detail. Using pdf works as expected. I'm guessing the call to the png device is not getting the correct parameters.

Comment: works for me with latest R and ggplot2_0.9.3 on Mac OS 10.8.2

Comment: does `png('test.png') ; plot(1,1); dev.off()` work in the first place?

Comment: I am quite happy with pdf(...); ...; dev.off() on mac. Then the PDF file can be converted to any file with any resolution you need